# TTButton not shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20

I use the following code to add TTButton in my **loadView** method:

```
TTButton* button2 = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"forwardActionButton:" title:@"Login"];
[button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(245, 160, 65, 33)];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
```

But the button does not appear.

Do you know what am I missing here? (I did #import  in my header file)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet looks fine. Where are you declaring the "forwardActionButton" style? It's not a three20 existing TTStyle as far as I know. Any custom styles should be in a style sheet class and should be loaded in the app delegate, as such:

```
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[StyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

You can also try it with an existing TTStyle, such as "toolbarForwardButton:" and see if that's works.

Here's a working example on using TTButton and setting a function selector as the button's target:

```
TTButton* storyButton = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarRoundButton:" title:@"Open Full Story"];

storyButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
storyButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50);

[storyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentFullStory) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[storyButton sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:storyButton];
```